# BIRT Reporting: Web Service Data Source doesn't return data

Tags: java, xml, reporting, birt

I'm trying to retrieve data from a webservice using the BIRT data source. The data that the server gives me as response looks something like this:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:kpi="http_adress">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <kpi:someMethod>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <SomeList>
            <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
            <SomeVariable oid="R2D2" versionNr="1.0">
               <!--Optional:-->
               <Variable1>10</Variable1>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <Variable2>Value</Variable2>
            </SomeVariable >
         </SomeList>
      </kpi:someMethod>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

My problem is that the data sets in BIRT only go 3 levels deep. It basically tells me to select the  line as a data row.

How do I get those Variable1 and Variable2 in the Data Set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't solve this using the row mapping, since the webservices contained complex datastructures, so I just used a scripted data source instead, and first loaded the data from the webservice in java objects (using axis2) before loading them in the reports.

Answer (score 0):

If your row mapping points to SomeList then you should be able to choose variable1 and variable2 in the column mapping.